# How do you set Opengl Line width in GLSL without geometry shader, is it even possible?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lines

Does anyone know how I can set OpenGL line width using GLSL 4.0?  I read something about geometry shader, I am knowing there is another application orientated way to set the line width.

I have tried glLineWidth, without any affect.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create your context with the forward compatibility set? If so, then that turns off line width. The line width is deprecated, but not *removed*. So it's still required to be supported and part of core OpenGL 4.3.

So stop using the forward compatibility bit.

Comment: If you're using GLUT: `glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);`

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg: ***NO!*** You do not need the compatibility profile. Deprecated *does not mean removed!* Line width is *core* behavior; it's just deprecated in the core. If people would just stop setting the pointless forward-compatibility bit, they wouldn't run into this problem.

Comment: Alright, after reading through [this](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt), I admit that my comment wasn't exactly well-informed. Mr. Bolas was referring to not using the `WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB` in `WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB`, which is called `GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE` in freeglut (not GLUT).

Comment: I was using glfw. Setting `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_FALSE);` saved my day.